# Is it common for a developer to keep their NAnt.exe.config file in version control?

Tags: nant

Is it common for a developer to keep their NAnt global configuration file (NAnt.exe.config) in version control?

And should or shouldn't the the rest of the files in the NAnt installation be added to the ignore file of the version control system?

Answer (score 1):

One use of version control is as a **backup**. If the only copy of `NAnt.exe.config` is on a hard disk that dies, it will take some effort to reconstruct it (along with everything else that disappeared and wasn't backed up).

From the corporate perspective, having all of the work in progress backed up is a method for preserving assets. The corporate owner of the source code asset is assured that the asset will not be destroyed.

When there is another backup strategy, then sometimes the rule of thumb is not to put anything into version control that should not be shared with other developers. Such as  customized data relevant only to one user and/or machine, or confidential information.

Comment: So you're basically saying it doesn't belong in version control, it belongs in a corporate backup file?

Comment: If version control is used for backup AND it's OK for other developers to see its contents, then I would say it's OK to put it in version control. Some organizations have systems for backing up confidential application files (such as config files containing production database connection strings) separately from the more widely accessible version control system. Just keeping a backup copy somewhere that nobody would know to look wouldn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

I keep a copy of the NAnt code for the version I'm using. This includes the .config file. This is so my build system is safe from "it disappeared from the internet" events (unlikely, but still).

Beyond that I see no reason to keep it around on *your* code repository, unless for some reason you've modified it somehow. Most everything in NAnt can be overridden in build files, like the target framework and so on.